# Script Windows settings configuration

Tags: windows, powershell

I am working in an environment where we deploy laptop images via SCCM task sequence for various countries that require specific settings. I'm looking for input, suggestions and feedback regarding the following configurations that are made manually after deployment. This are the things we configure mostly after deploying a laptop:

Power settings:

- Change: When I close the lid: Do nothing
- Turn off: Turn on fast startup (recommended)

Software Center:

- run 2 packages

In what way should I approach to automate these small tasks? Powershell, batch, AHK? Preferably using templates per country/laptop? Please note GPO is not an option for now. All feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've looked at the IP address of the client to determine where the client is and then take action based on that, assuming each site has a unique IP address range.  Something like this PowerShell snippet:

```
function checkipaddress()

{

 $IPAddresses = (get-netipaddress).ipaddress

 if (($IPAddresses -like "192.168.81.*") -or ($IPAddresses -like "192.168.82.*") )

 { 
 write-host "In London"
 <then do something>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set power setting in SCCM admin console and apply those setting to the collections and task sequence variable to apply different steps for the different regions  If you have different collections setup for the endpoints and their regions you should be able to complete these task via SCCM.